# Is there a way to use a default handle that all the controllers using a particular layout.xml file use that handle?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, controllers

I was creating 4-5 controllers, all of which would use the same template-block files

so, was wondering if there was a way to assign same template-block without changing the the handles, i.e without copy pasting the same thing for all the handles..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this either by using an update handles, which will essentially add a complete layout handle inside another one.

```
<your_default_handle>
    <!-- add your blocks -->
</your_default_handle>
```

Then on each controller handle you can use this handle.

```
<controller_handle>
    <update handle="your_default_handle" />
    <!-- make any changes that you need -->
</controller_handle>
```

The other option is to add the handle in your controller. This can be done via the following code:

```
$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('your_default_handle');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.
Create your own handle that looks like this.

```
<my_handle>
    <!-- blocks go here -->
</my_handle>
```

Now you can include your handle in the handle of your action:

```
<module_controller_action>
    <update handle="my_handle" />
    <!-- additional blocks go here if you need them -->
<module_controller_action>
```